# Adding Custom Tag to Sentry with Python

Tags: python, sentry, raven

I'm trying to add a custom tag on Sentry to show up on the 'Tags' column. I've tried using logging and raven, but both methods do not show up on the 'Tags' column.

raven:

```
client.capture("raven.events.Message", message='foo', data={'tags':{'customtag':'AAAA'}})
```

logging:

```
logger.info('foo', extra={'tags': {'customtag':'AAAA'}})
```

This is registering on Sentry as:
[image]

But it is not showing up on the Tags column itself.

[image]

I see the custom tag showing up on the search box but I can't seem to actually filter based on this custom tag. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: It can take a minute or two for all parts of Sentry's UI to be updated, as the event goes through the pipeline. If it's still not happening, it may be a bug, please write into support@.